# K&R exercise 5-3: passing pointers to functions

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100
void str_cat(char *s, char *t);

int main()
{
    char a[MAX] = "Hello, ";
    char b[MAX] = "world!";
    char *p;
    char *q;
    p = a;
    q = b;
    str_cat(*p, *q);
    printf("The new string is %s.\n", a);

    return 0;
}

void str_cat(char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s++)
        ;
    while (*s++ = *t++)
        ;
}
```

Compiler errors:

```
str_cat.c: In function ‘main’:
str_cat.c:13:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘str_cat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   str_cat(*p, *q);
           ^
str_cat.c:3:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 void str_cat(char *s, char *t);
      ^~~~~~~
str_cat.c:13:15: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘str_cat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   str_cat(*p, *q);
               ^
str_cat.c:3:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
```

Comment: What's the question? The compiler is pretty clear.

Comment: Yeah, compiler errors are meant to be _read_ by people. Compiler writers spend a lot of time thinking about error reporting systems and their possible implementations, they strive to make error messages as clear as possible (admittedly, sometimes they aren't so successful, but still). Did you _read_ this error message? What does it mean?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Why does it give me this warning?

Comment: _Did you read this warning?_ It's very clear: `void str_cat(char *, char *);` expects its two parameters to be _pointers_, but you're passing just two `char`s.

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake. I didn't realize the *p is char s.

Comment: @WENWEN `str_cat(*p, *q);` => `str_cat(p, q);`

Answer (score 0):

The call to `str_cat(char *, char *)` in `main()` is incorrect. If you take a pointer like `char *p = a;`, then `*p` is an expression that allows you to access the memory that p references. Hence doing *p on a pointer is called de-referencing. It is not what you want in this case since str_cat expects a pointer and not a value. My example below does what you intended. You can see that declaring the additional pointers is not necessary.

```
int main()
{
    char a[MAX] = "Hello, ";
    char b[MAX] = "world!";
    str_cat(a, b);
    printf("The new string is %s.\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*p` evaluates to the memory location, not the stored value.  You could use that expression to retrieve the stored value, but there are other uses that do not retrieve the stored value, e.g. `*p = 'x'`

Answer (score 0):

In the str_cat function you should pass str_cat(p,q) instead of str_cat(*p, *q).
And there is a problem with your code in this function. At the first while loop, the while loop will be ended when *s = '\0'. and increment s to the next address. So at the next while loop the string that the pointer s points to will include the '\0' character. The result will be like this: "Hello, '\0'world!". So after the str_cat() call, the string a still "Hello, ". This code should work as you expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100
void str_cat(char *s, char *t);

int main()
{
    char a[MAX] = "Hello, ";
    char b[MAX] = "world!";
    char *p;
    char *q;
    p = a;
    q = b;
    str_cat(p, q);
    printf("The new string is %s.\n", a);

    return 0;
}

void str_cat(char *s, char *t)
{
    while(*s)
        s++;
    while(*s++ = *t++);
}
```